# Should the button target method logic be defined in UIView or UIViewController

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, design-patterns, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a button and a textview defined in a UIView Class. Which will make a networks request when pressed. Should i add the button.addTarget in UIView or UIViewController. what is the MVC way to do it.

```
class MessageInputView: UIView {

    let send_button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        textView.clipsToBounds = true
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 19.5
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.inputTextViewColor.cgColor
        return textView
    }()
}


class ChatMessagesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    let messageInputView = MessageInputView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        messageInputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(messageInputView)
        setMessagesInputViewConstraints()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have custom class for your view element, you should declare `IBAction` in that class, but the logic should be happening in the view controller (or other responsible class in other architectures).

You can establish connection between view and view controller via delegate pattern or with the help of closures, whichever fits your code better.

Here's the example of the closure:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
  // ...
  var buttonHandler: (() -> Void)?

  @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttonHandler?()
  }
  // ...
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  // ...
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    customView.buttonHander = { print("User clicked the button") }
  }
}
```

Comment: would it be ok to just call `messageInputView.send_button.addTarget()` inside the view controller and handle the function there

Comment: What would this closure look like. can you give an example ?

Comment: That's actually is breaking incapsulation. View controller should know nothing about how user's actions are delivered. If you decide to change button with some other (custom?) control, you would be forced to do the changes in several places, as opposed to just re-implement only the view element.

Comment: so should i add the target in the UIView class and then call a delegate function in the view controller to handle the networks request. WIll that be something like `messageInputView.send_button.delegate = self`

Comment: Edited reply to add closure example.

Comment: Thanks! What if i add the request to the Model as suggested by the second answer. What exactly would that look like ? I'm just very confused about where to put different logic

Comment: Is there any book or resource you recommend on design pattern for ios

Comment: First of all, I would recommend switching from MVC to some other architecture. This is of course disputable, but MVC has already proven being non-optimal. Try to google and read basics of MVVM (if you like functional/reactive way) or MVP (if you prefer to stick to imperative paradigm) and select one of those.

Comment: As to your model question, that's a broad topic. In a couple of words: Model should perform network requests, but view controller should ask it to do that. Like somewhere in view controller class
`customView.buttonHanlder = { self.model.refreshSomethingOnBackground() }`

Comment: so if this was MVVM the button would send a request to the model. what exactly would that look like. Can you give a simple example? thanks!

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Read about the MVVM. Things are different there.

Comment: Hey, Would you recommend this book [https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/design-patterns-by-tutorials] for learning design patterns for ios

Comment: I didn't have a chance to get to know it, but I think one cannot underestimate Ray Wenderlich's impact on iOS industry.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the difference between the model, view, and controller.

1. The **view** is how the user interacts with the application. It should *only* be concerned with getting input data from the user and sending output data to the user. Any other operations should be delegated to something that is not the view.
2. The **model** is how the application handles its required operations. It should not know or care about how/where the result of those operations is being used. It simply performs a requested action and returns the result to the requester.
3. The **controller** is what sets up the communication pathways/adapters between the view and the model. It is the only entity that knows both the view and the model exist; they should not know about the existence of each other or the controller, since they don't have to care about it. All they need is an adapter that allows them to communicate with some external entity, which the controller provides.

Given this information, it makes sense to me that your button, when clicked, should make a request to the thing(s) that handle its requests through its adapter. That adapter routes the request to the model, which performs the operation and returns the result. Thus, the view knows nothing about where its request is going or where the response is coming from, and the model has no idea that the view is the one requesting the action and response. This preserves encapsulation.

Comment: This is too vague. Can you give an example of what this would look like ?